# git client and rsa authentication

Tags: git, rsa

I've installed git client on windows 7 on administrator account. On first pull git asked me if i wanted to add host to trusted locations. After that '.ssh' folder was creted in user home. When i placed my key 'id_rsa' in it I was able to pull from remote repository. I've created new windows user and tried to repeat the routine but i kept getting fatal error: "the remote end hung up unexpectedly". Any idea what may be the reason of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to run ssh-agent (shipped with git) and add ppk key there?
2. Try to create "config" file in .ssh directory with following content:
   Host ${repo_host}
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key

Comment: 1. i tried after reading your post with no effect, 2. i didn't try this, i got it working by using ssh from git\bin instead of plink from putty family